# Own LDAP Password Attribute

Tags: authentication, ldap, schema, customization

Welcome!

I am currently playing with custom schemas in LDAP (OpenLDAP). I have create my own user objectclass which requires its own password attribute.

Is is possible to use another password attribute than "userPassword" (e.g. my own attribute)?

The core.schema is not required in openldap so there should be a possible solution.

Any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, RFC 3112 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3112) defines the authPassword and an authPasswordSyntax (so you can define your own attribute with that syntax).
This is supported by many LDAP servers, including OpenDJ and OpenLDAP.

Comment: Well, first I want to define my own attribute type for a password. Do I have to use "authAttributeObject"?

Comment: No idea, but I would think that OpenLDAP can do this. I know OpenDJ can do it (but I'm working for the OpenDJ project).

Comment: It seems that OpenLDAP initiated RFC 3112 but they didn't implement it yet. I have to use the old attribute.

Comment: Well, OpenLDAP is an open source project... Contributions are welcome !